# Custom font breaks caret's position in Bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

While using Bootstrap 3 with custom font in navbar the position of carot doesn't remain vertically aligned with text.

[image]

I'm not using any custom classes - just `li` elements with `.active` and `.dropdown` respectively, only `font-family` was changed. I guess that the issue has to do with font's height itself.

How can I fix this issue without hacking carot's position? I'm building Bootstrap with LESS, so if there are any relevant variables corresponding for something like basic font height (or maybe line-height?) let me know.

Edit: Providing code example (just an ordinary navbar)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Link <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>          
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container -->
</nav>
```

Comment: which custom font you are using? code example?

Comment: provide the code please.

Comment: Edited the question with code example. I'm using the [Stolzl font](https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/northernblock/stolzl/).

Answer (score 0):

The caret already has a class in bootstrap.  I would recommend using that for positioning.

```
.caret {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top: 4px dashed;
  border-top: 4px solid \9;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: Not sure that I understand what you mean by "hacking carot's position." If you don't want to modify the core bootstrap CSS and have it affect all carets throughout the site, then you can either (1) create a separate CSS file for bootstrap overrides, or (2) add a line to an existing non-bootstrap CSS file. You can then qualify your CSS so that it only applies to the navigation. Maybe something like:

`nav.navbar ul.navbar-nav .caret {margin-top: -3px}`

Answer (score 0):

You can put the caret in a span:

```
<li class="dropdown">
                <a class="dropdown-toggle" style="font-size: large" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">HasDropdowns<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
```

Comment: This is a hackfix only for caret. The issue is, I believe, related to the height of the font itself. What if it breaks something else? I'm looking for solution which fixes it without interfering with caret class.

Comment: @Selenir I increased by style font-size: large, and the caret was vertically aligned.  Can you please tell us the custom css font you used?